# How to check every row of a table to continue my loop?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm stuck with this problem because my loop stops at only the first row of the table. Every customer has a set budget for purchasing products which resets every week to purchase items if ever the qty is not equal to 0. The admin is the one who can process the order for the customer. Customers have a budget = 1000 from customers table. Then customer_product table has the qty of products to be purchased by the customer. For example product_id = 1 has a price of 20 and has the qty of 10 so 20 x 10 = 200. Budget would be deducted by 200, remaining budget would be 800 after looping through the first row. Now i want to continue looping through the 2nd row with the remaining 800 budget instead of the 1000. It continues to loop as long as he still has a budget.
Database tables

```
customer  
id | name | budget    

customer_product   
product_id | cus_id | qty | status  

products  
id | name | price
```

Controller

```
public function processOrder($id)  
{  
 $customers = Customer::find($id);
  foreach ($customers->products as $product) 
  {
    $status = $product->pivot->status;
    $budget = $product-budget;
    $price = $product->price;
    $qty = $product->pivot->qty;

    if ($status == 1) {

          $i = $qty;

          for ($i; $i > 0; $i--) { 
            if ($budget < 1) {
              break;
            } else {
              $budget-=$price;
            }

          }
  };
  echo "Status 0";
 }
}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('processOrder/{id}', ['as' => 'processOrder',
        'uses' => 'AdminController@processOrder']);
```

I can process the first row of the table and when it reaches 0 qty with my for loop, it stops there and doesn't continue to process the next row even though his budget is still enough to purchase products from the next row. Can someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: `echo "Status 0"; break;` the loop will exit at this point surely and never progress beyond the first iteration

Comment: @RamRaider my bad it continues the loop through the next row, but it still it doesn't continue the remaining budget. It resets to the base budget instead of the remaining budget after the purchase of the first row.

Comment: what is purpose of `for ($i; $i > 0; $i--) { ` loop ?

Comment: @user2486 That's for checking the qty, as long as the qty is still not 0 it continues to loop until it reaches 0.

Comment: why not you just put it to `0` directly as you are not using this variable any where

Comment: @user2486  Oh i'm using it here $i = $qty; im just assigning it to $qty column value from the customer_product table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the customer's budget before going into the loop, then update it while you iterate through the products.

```
public function processOrder($id)  
{  
    $customer = Customer::find($id);
    $remainingBudget = $customer->budget;

    foreach ($customer->products as $product) {

        // Calculate the total price to get the desired qty of product
        $cost = $product->price * $product->pivot->qty;

        // If we have enough remaining budget go ahead with the purchase
        if ($product->pivot->status == 1 && $remainingBudget >= $cost) {

            // Decrease the remaining budget
            $remainingBudget -= $cost;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry wasn't clear about the status part, so my pivot table has a status column which is either 1(active) and 0(inactive). So it only processes the products that are active. My bad again for not explaining my tables well. Oh and the last part the echo, i was just checking if the function went through or not.

Comment: Your codes works it got the cost of all the rows involved thank you. Ill try to add more and understand on this first to make it display what i need. Thank you and ill might ask you again if its okay if i need any clarifications.

Comment: @jesserodriguez If the answer solved your problem don't forget to accept it! Post comments here if you need to clarify something about this question or one of it's answers but ask a new question on any other case, check [ask] if in doubt

Answer (score 0):

You are forcing the loop to break at the very first index

`echo "Status 0"; break;`

So remove `break;` at the end.

update:

```
foreach($customers->products as $product){
$status = $product->pivot->status;
$budget = $product-budget;
$price = $product->price;
$qty = $product->pivot->qty;

if($status == 1){

    do {

         if($budget < 1) break;
         $budget -=$price;


    } while ($qty != 0);
 }
}
```

Comment: Kinda missed that break sorry bout that, but the problem still is here. Because even though it processes the 2nd row of the table. The budget it uses is the base budget instead of the remaining budget after the purchase of the 1st row. My base budget is 1000 so after processing the 1st row, the 2nd row still uses the 1000 budget instead of the remaining budget.

Comment: ``` $status = $product->pivot->status;
    $budget = $product-budget;
    $price = $product->price;
    $qty = $product->pivot->qty; ```  place them out of foreach loop

Comment: I placed them out of the foreach loop now, but now it only loops the first row. I don't see the 2nd row anymore.

Comment: @jesserodriguez what are you trying to get with this code

Comment: Okay, 1st i have a budget = 1000 from customers table.  Then customer_product table has the qty of products to be purchased by the customer. For example product_id = 1 has a price of 20 and has the qty of 10 so 20 x 10 = 200. Budget would be deducted by 200, remaining budget would be 800 after looping through the first row. Now i want to continue looping through the 2nd row with the remaining 800 budget instead of the 1000. It continues to loop as long as he still has a budget.

Comment: I tried your updated answer, and it produces the same output as my previous code. It still uses the 1000 budget instead of the remaining one.